# Why a clpfd variable is assigned to an actual value in a reification?

Tags: list, prolog, swi-prolog, clpfd

I'm working on a (SWI-)Prolog program that uses CLP(FD) constraints to find a solution for a particular problem. To do so, I happen to need what I call an "unpositioned" overlapping of two lists. That is:

- List `La` has length A
- List `Lb` has length B
- A > B
- The unpositioned overlapping list is `La+Lb`, where elements are added in a one-by-one fashion.

However, I need `Lb` to have a **variable offset** (i.e. each lists' first element are not in the same position for the `La+Lb` addition. However, list `Lb` is always within the width of `La`. For instance:

Be `La = [0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1]` and `Lb = [1,2,2]`.

**Possible case 1**

```
(Lb) 1 2 2 . . . . . . ---> offset = 0
(La) 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1
( +) 1 3 3 1 1 0 1 1 1
```

**Possible case 2**

```
(Lb) . . . 1 2 2 . . . ---> offset = 3
(La) 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1
( +) 0 1 1 2 3 2 1 1 1
```

**Possible case 3**

```
(Lb) . . . . . 1 2 2 . ---> offset = 5
(La) 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1
( +) 0 1 1 1 1 1 3 3 1
```

What I want is to define the `offset` as a *clpfd* variable with a particular domain associated to it. In order to compute `La+Lb` I've written the predicate `overlap/6`, which is the following:

```
overlap([],[],_,_,_,[]) :- !.
overlap([],_, _,_,_,[]) :- !.
overlap(A, [],_,_,_, A) :- !.
overlap(A, _,Os,_,_, A) :- length(A,L), L =< Os, !.
overlap([A|As],[B|Bs],0,Os,S,[A|Ls]) :-  % Os is the actual Offset 
    A #= B #<== S #= Os,                 % S is a clpfd variable
    overlap(As,Bs,0,Os,S,Ls),!.
overlap([A|As],Bs,Acc,Os,S,[A|Ls]) :-
    Acc > 0,
    Acc0 is Acc-1,
    overlap(As,Bs,Acc0,Os,S,Ls),!.
```

The idea is to find `La+Lb` by calling `overlap/6` then, with `indomain(S)`, make the numbers converge to a particular solution of the addition. My problem is that when Prolog reaches the line `A #= B #<==> S #= Os`, `S` is assigned to `Os` (a case offset value), rather to constrain `A` with a reified condition.

Am I crazy and this makes no sense? Is there any proper way to do what I'm trying? Thanks in advance!

**Edit:** The idea is to call `overlap/6` for every point within `S`'s domain, and use this constraining list to label a proper `S` afterwards.

Example of unification:

```
?- S in 0..2,
   L0 = [0,0,0,0],
   overlap(L0, [1,2], 0, S, L1),
   overlap(L1, [1,2], 1, S, L2),
   overlap(L2, [1,2], 2, S, L).
L = [_G1, _G2, _G3, _G4]

_G1 in 0\/1
_G2 in 0\/1\/2
_G3 in 0\/1\/2
_G4 in 0\/2

_G1 #= 1 #<== S #= 0
_G1 #= 0 #<== S #> 0

_G2 #= 2 #<== S #= 0
_G2 #= 1 #<== S #= 1
_G2 #= 0 #<== S #> 2

_G3 #= 0 #<== S #= 0
_G3 #= 2 #<== S #= 1
_G3 #= 1 #<== S #< 2

_G1 #= 0 #<== S #= 0
_G4 #= 0 #<== S #= 1
_G4 #= 2 #<== S #= 2
```

Or:

```
?- S in 0..2,
   L0 = [0,0,0,0],
   overlap(L0, [1,2], 0, S, L1),
   overlap(L1, [1,2], 1, S, L2),
   overlap(L2, [1,2], 2, S, L),
   indomain(S).
S = 0
L = [1, 2, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Constraints and ! don't flock together. Try first to state when your definition should succeed and when it should fail.

Comment: In fact, it should always succeed... `!` are there just to cut (the rest of) unwanted solutions.

Comment: You say "it should always succeed". No, definitely not, otherwise `overlap(_,_,_,_,_,_).` would be a perfect implementation!

Comment: Right. It should succeed when: `La` and `Lb` are lists of any length AND their lengths are `A>=B` AND the offset is bound to an actual number (`>=0`) AND and `S` (the final offset) is __not__ bound to a number but has a bounded and well known domain. Is that what you meant? (I edited the question, btw)

Comment: Give concrete examples! It really helps.

Comment: I've added two examples of unification. I'm not sure if you were asking for something like that. Hope it helps, though. And just to state that clear, both lists always "overlap". Maybe the predicate name isn't helping...

Comment: That was quite an old post. Thanks for your comment! Is there an actual reason why this is a bad idea in this particular program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is an overlap with starting position `S`, we expect a *conjunction* of constraints so that all overlapping positions are covered. For example:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

overlap_at(As, Bs, S, ABs) :-
        length(As, L),
        L1 #= L - 1,
        S in 0..L1,
        overlap_at_(As, Bs, S, 0, ABs).

overlap_at_([], _, _, _, []).
overlap_at_([A|As], Bs, S, N0, [AB|ABs]) :-
        overlap_here(Bs, [A|As], [AB|ABs], Conj),
        S #= N0 #==> Conj,
        S #> N0 #==> AB #= A,
        N1 #= N0 + 1,
        overlap_at_(As, Bs, S, N1, ABs).

overlap_here(_, [], _, 1) :- !.
overlap_here([], _, _, 1).
overlap_here([B|Bs], [A|As], [AB|ABs], (AB #= A + B #/\ Rest)) :-
        overlap_here(Bs, As, ABs, Rest).
```

Notice how I describe a conjunction in `overlap_here/4`.

Sample query:

```
?- overlap_at([0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1], [1,2,2], 3, ABs).
ABs = [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, _G909, _G912, _G915],
_G909 in inf..sup,
_G912 in inf..sup,
_G915 in inf..sup.
```

This gives you a good chunk of the solution: All elements up to *and including* the overlap are instantiated as desired. The third argument can of course also be a variable: Try for example

```
?- overlap_at([0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1], [1,2,2], S, ABs), 
   indomain(S), writeln(ABs), false.
```

Which yields something like:

```
[1,3,3,_,_,_,_,_,_]
[0,2,3,3,_,_,_,_,_]
[0,1,2,3,3,_,_,_,_]
[0,1,1,2,3,2,_,_,_]
[0,1,1,1,2,2,3,_,_]
[0,1,1,1,1,1,3,3,_]
[0,1,1,1,1,0,2,3,3]
[0,1,1,1,1,0,1,2,3]
[0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,2]
```

I leave the rest as an exercise: Trailing positions that are not affected by the overlap need to be made equal to elements of `A`. Also, you may want to further restrict the possible positions of the overlap, which I have kept rather general.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That seemed quite brilliant to me. I used `overlap_here([], [A|As], [AB|ABs], (AB #= A #/\ Rest)) :-
    overlap_here([], As, ABs, Rest).` to also consider those elements not affected by the overlap.