# How can I avoid an "out of global stack" error in SWI-Prolog?

Tags: list, prolog, out-of-memory, swi-prolog, clpfd

I have a (SWI-)Prolog program that uses CLP(FD) variables in an utterly massive way (²). I am moving lists of CLP(FD) items in and out of several predicates (¹), and their constraints grow exponentially. My code works for small lists, but when I try to use it for long lists of elements (where the amount of constraints for each element becomes enormous) I end up with an **Out of global stack** error.

My point is whether I can use a different method for passing such huge arguments without using the stack. My first thought was to use `asserta` to store the intermediate results in the dynamic database but I'm not sure if I'll be able to store uninstantiated variables or CLP(FD) constraints that way. And I don't know if this is an optimal solution either...

---

**¹ MORE DETAILS:** What I need is an overlap of N lists of length L where the first elements are offseted. However, the offsets are not bound but are CLP(FD) variables.

**² EVEN MORE DETAILS:** Basically, I have a number of lists where each element has thousands of constraints. Each element constraints are basically holding information about its value, which is linked to a "*master-variable*" value. Depending on the *master-variable*'s value, each list item will have a value or another.

Since I already had problems with the implementation of such list generator and I asked here for some advice, you can see the actual list-maker predicate, `overlap_at/5`, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20688099/why-a-clpfd-variable-is-assigned-to-an-actual-value-in-a-reification/20691396#20691396).

`overlap_lists/4` is the predicate which is issuing the error (it **does** work fine for `Rs`'s lengths of less than 140 elements AND less than 10 `Cs` elements):

```
% Cs -> lists that have to be overlapped. Their items are integers.
% Ss -> Offsets per each list. They are CLP(FD) variables.
% Rs -> (not important here)
% Os -> List of overlapped elements.

overlap_lists(Cs,Ss,Rs,Os) :-
    length(Rs,L),
    zeros(Zs,L), % The initial list to overlap with is a list filled with zeros.
    overlap(Cs,Ss,Zs,Os),
    list_limit(Os,Rs). % Constrains the consumptions

overlap([],[],Fs,Fs) :- !.
overlap([C|Cs],[S|Ss],Os,Fs) :-
    fd_inf(S,Inf),
    overlap_at(Os,C,S,Inf,Os2),!,
    overlap(Cs,Ss,Os2,Fs).

overlap_at([], _, _, _, []).
overlap_at([A|As], Bs, S, N0, [AB|ABs]) :-
    overlap_here(Bs, [A|As], [AB|ABs], Conj),
    S #= N0 #==> Conj,
    S #> N0 #==> AB #= A,
    N1 #= N0 + 1,
    overlap_at(As, Bs, S, N1, ABs).

overlap_here(_, [], _, 1) :- !.
overlap_here([], [A|As], [AB|ABs], (AB #= A #/\ Rest)) :-
    overlap_here([], As, ABs, Rest).    
overlap_here([B|Bs], [A|As], [AB|ABs], (AB #= A + B #/\ Rest)) :-
    overlap_here(Bs, As, ABs, Rest).
```

Answer (score 4):

The first thing that comes to mind: Increase the global stack that SWI-Prolog allocates via

`swipl -G128M ...`

It may help you to read more about the Prolog stacks: For example, the *global* stack is not to be confused with the *local* stack. Passing arguments differently will typically not help you to decrease the global stack usage. Richard O'Keefes *The Craft of Prolog* contains a good discussion on where the space goes.

On 64-bit processors, the global stack can be larger than 128MB with SWI-Prolog, so for serious computations, you may need a 64-bit machine with a lot of RAM.

That being said, the code I posted uses only a polynomial, not exponential, amount of memory. If you are formulating the problem in such a way that it needs exponential space, you may first try to find a more (memory-)efficient formulation. The problem does not seem to require exponential space intrinsically.

If you need to preserve constraints over `assertz/1`, use `copy_term/3` to obtain the constraints as residual goals, and assert these residual goals along with the variables so that you can later reinstate the goals via `maplist(call, Gs)`.

Comment: Thanks for you kind and fast reply once again, @mat! I agree with you that it might probably take polynomial space to compute my problem (don't you think, though, that it strongly depends on the CLP(FD) library implementation?). Since I need to run my code on a 32-bit ARM machine with only 64 MB of RAM, I won't have a lot of memory available... The purpose of this program is to find a scheduling solution for tasks that consume a resource elastically (their resource consumption is variant over time).

Comment: That's why I need to overlap lists, because I need to check that the total consumption does not exceed the resource capacity. 
Moreover, I wanted to do so before having a `Start` for each task. That way, I would just simply call the overlapping predicate and afterwards `label(Starts)` to find a valid solution "instantaneously".

Comment: I have two suggestions that you can try: 1) Think about cases where you post constraints that are not needed. For example, can these tasks really overlap at *every* position, or can you maybe reduce the cases that need to be considered and not post these constraints at all, or post them in a simplified form? This can save space by avoiding unnecessary constraints. 2) You may implement a custom propagator that merges the huge conjunctions and thus saves space. I would first try (1), and if that is not enough, try (2). Also try the SWI tools to see the memory profile. (`profile/1` etc.).

Comment: One more comment: The resource consumption of a task can typically be described by a single finite domain variable for each time slot, even if it varies over time. So you may even manage to considerably limit the number of necessary lists if you reformulate the model a bit. Only you can tell (after thinking about them) which further simplifications are possible, since you know the complete task. The goal is clear in this case: Reduce the number of lists, reduce the number of constraints etc. I would try models that allow you to reduce these terms.

Comment: Yes, I am actually doing 1). Each task has a time domain out of which it can't be scheduled, and that is known a priori (it's actually the `Start` domain). But since this is completely circumstantial, I need to find other optimizations as well.

Comment: Implementing a custom propagator sounds like THE solution, but I wouldn't know where to start or how to make it more efficient that the provided one. Oh, and I always used `time/1` to get a little information about my calls. `profile/1` has just opened the door to a new world to me. What is all this information? What is this profiler? I'll definitely look for it!! Thanks!